# change icon in navbar collapse bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

i have a navbar and it has one problem in sm size

i add a icon for collapse dropdown

when i click in one dropdown it will be open and the icon is "-" and when click again on the same dropdown the icon is "+" and work perfectly.

when i click in one dropdown it will be open and the icon is "-"
and when it is open and click to another dropdown , the previous dropdown will be close but the previous icon still "-"

this is my code

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  nav_t fixed-top pt-2  navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
    <div class="container ">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdown">
                        home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown px-md-5">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle sm_display"
                        href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/" id="navbarDropdown"
                        role="button" data-toggle="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        articles
                    </a>
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle d-md-none  d-sm-inline float-left plus_icon maqale" href="#"
                        id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-square " id=""></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href=""> 1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href=""> 2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href=""> 3</a>

                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle sm_display "  href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/" id="navbarDropdown" role="" data-toggle=""
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        courses
                    </a>
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle d-md-none d-sm-inline float-left plus_icon maqale" href="#"
                        id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-square " id=""></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href=""> 1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href=""> 2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href=""> 3</a>

                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown px-md-5 ">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle   sm_display  "  href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/" id="navbarDropdown" role="" data-toggle=""
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        news
                    </a>
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle d-md-none  d-sm-inline float-left plus_icon maqale" href="#"
                        id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-square " id=""></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

                        <a class="dropdown-item" href=""> 1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href=""> 2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href=""> 3</a>

                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and this is javascript

```
 $(".plus_icon").click(function () {
        $(this).children(".fa").toggleClass("fa-plus-square");
        $(this).children(".fa").toggleClass("fa-minus-square");
    });
```

what should i add to javascript to show currect icon?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily. From what I understand from your question is that you what to change the "+" icon to "-" when the dropdown is open and then change it back again but you aren't able to change it back.
If this is the case, but first of all since I don't know jQuery, I will give the answer in vanilla JavaScript. So what you can do is when the dropdown is clicked, you will say:

```js
// change the variable names
if(dropdown.classlist.contains("opened")){
    dropdown.classList.remove("opened");
}else {
    dropdown.classList.add("opened")
}
```

Now add some JavaScript to check if the dropdown contains the class and change icon accordingly. For e.g.

```js
if(dropdown.classlist.contains("opened")){
    // change the icon
    //remove the class
}else {
    // change the icon
    //add the class
}
```

Comment: thank you but it doesent work with javascript

Comment: @mmad i tried with some other code and it works

Comment: @mmad here's what I wrote

Comment: `function doneTodo(e) {
    if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains("done")) {
        e.target.parentElement.classList.remove("done");
        e.target.parentElement.querySelector(".todoContent").style =
            "text-decoration: none;opacity: 1";
    } else {
        e.target.parentElement.classList.add("done");
        e.target.parentElement.querySelector(".todoContent").style =
            "text-decoration: line-through;opacity: 0.5";
    }
}`

Comment: tnx bro for helping me but vanilla JavaScript is different with js

Comment: look at this website https://toplearn.com/ and it navbar in sm

Comment: it is my second option if i could not wrote that code

Comment: do you know what should i do to open dropdown like this site in sm?

Comment: @mmad What is sm?

Comment: I can see a dropdown on hover tho